# Geth in non-mining mode and Etherem Wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethereum-wallet-dapp

If I start Geth node this way:

`/home/porton/bin/geth --datadir ~/private_ethereum_blockchain --networkid 100 --nodiscover --nat none --mine --minerthreads 1 --ipcpath /home/porton/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi 'web3,eth,debug,net,shh' --rpccorsdomain '*'`

and then start Ethereum Wallet, then Ethereum Wallet connects to the local node and uses it as a peer.

If I however remove `--mine --minerthreads 1` from the above command, then when I start Ethereum Wallet it stalls with "Looking for peers..." message and cannot use my local node.

Why? And how to use Ethereum Wallet with a local Geth node without mining? (Mining disturbs my testing because it causes unintended changes of balances.)